# Tools seems to lag behind Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb

Ever since updating to the latest ADT (version 18), I've noticed that there seems to be some sort of odd lag between what's happening on device emulators and what various tools are seeing. For instance, if I set a breakpoint in Eclipse and then attach the debugger to a running app, the debugger will miss the first time that the breakpoint is reached, breaking only on subsequent executions. Similarly, if I try to take a screen snapshot with the Devices view, the image is always from one or two screen changes back. Similar behavior happens if I run `hierarchyviewer` outside of Eclipse, so I don't think it's an Eclipse problem specifically.

I should mention that the part of the app that I've tested this with has static screens that change only on user input (that is, no animations or background threads); so it's not just a communication lag. I can change screens, wait five minutes, take a screen snapshot, and still get an image of what had previously been on the screen. Screen snapshots in perticular never seem to catch up. (Repeating the snapshot still generates the previous screen, not the one on display.)

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Does anyone know how to fix it?

UPDATE: This is on a Windows 7 machine running Java 1.6.0_26 and Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

Comment: **"Has anyone else seen this behavior?"** seems there was an implied *"No, but I will upvote this question in any case"* here -- sort of bizarre... (good luck)

Comment: Is this with old emulator builds or new ones since they've added GPU and device sensor injection.

Comment: @Morrison - Good question. I'm seeing this on rev. 3 of the Android 1.6 (API 4) emulator, which I think has been around for a while. I'll try it on an emulator for a more recent API and see whether the behavior changes. I suspect there's something going on with the adb, but I have no idea how to diagnose this.

Comment: When I mean emulator builds, I mean ones that have been created regardless of API level. The newer tools changed stuff under the hood so an emulator build from a year ago has slightly different behavior than one built today.

Comment: @Morrison - All the tools are at the latest revision. As I say, I don't know when rev. 3 of the API 4 tools was installed, but I suppose that it includes the latest "stuff under the hood".

Comment: Yes but when did you create your AVD emulator builds? Just now or are you using ones from 6 months ago when you installed the SDK (for example). My point is that 'old AVD emulator builds' may behave differently than newer ones due to tool changes.

Comment: @Morrison - Ah. I created the AVDs quite a while ago, but I edited them fairly recently (to increase the SD card size and enable snapshots, iirc). I don't know whether the problems started before or after I did the editing.

Comment: @Morrison - Recreating the AVDs seems to have fixed this. If you could turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google/Android team have been enhancing the emulator images with the ADT updates like GPU support and sensor injection. If you are using old emulator builds (AVDs) from when you first created your work environment (say months ago) you will want to recreate them fresh from the new tools and see if the problem resolves.